# Class invariant for mutually exclusive conditions

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

My class has two private fields and three constructors.

One constructor is a default constructor that does not assign any values.

The remaining constructors each instantiate one of two fields, ensuring that one field is *always* `null` and the other field is *never* `null`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly Foo foo;
    public Foo InstanceOfFoo { get { return this.foo; } }

    private readonly Bar bar;
    public Bar InstanceOfBar { get { return this.bar; } }

    // Default constructor: InstanceOfFoo == null & InstanceOfBar == null
    public MyClass()
    {
    }

    // Foo constructor: InstanceOfFoo != null & InstanceOfBar == null
    public MyClass(Foo foo)
    {
        Contract.Requires(foo != null);
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    // Bar constructor: InstanceOfFoo == null & InstanceOfBar != null
    public MyClass(Bar bar)
    {
        Contract.Requires(bar != null);
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Now I need to add a class invariant method that specifies that `InstanceOfFoo` and `InstanceOfBar` are mutually exclusive: both can be `null`, but only one of them can be something other than `null`.

How do I express that in code?

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ObjectInvariant()
{
    // How do I complete this invariant method?
    Contract.Invariant((this.InstanceOfFoo == null && this.InstanceOfBar == null) || ...);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like simple OR should be enougth:

```
Contract.Invariant(this.InstanceOfFoo == null || this.InstanceOfBar == null);
```

Proof (for someone, who downvoted :)

```
1. (null, null): true  || true  -> true
2. (inst, null): false || true  -> true
3. (null, inst): true  || false -> true
4. (inst, inst): false || false -> false
```

Comment: Could you translate that to plain English? My brain hurts when I try to sum up all possible configurations that fit this contract.

Comment: @StevenLiekens please see my update with a proof-table

Comment: Thanks! I love how you lay out the proof. I need to start doing that.